# Using the value of a variable which is just created in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the  below data.table:

```
df <- data.table(abc = rep(1:5,2), xyz = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)))

     abc xyz
 1:   1   1
 2:   2   1
 3:   3   1
 4:   4   1
 5:   5   1
 6:   1   2
 7:   2   2
 8:   3   2
 9:   4   2
10:   5   2
```

I want to create a column 'q1' such that :

- When 'abc' equals to 'one' the value of 'q1' is **0.25 * xyz**. But,
- When 'abc' not equls to 'one' the value of 'q1' is **(0.25 * xyz) + (0.75 * shift(q1))**

But since q1 is not already created I cannot use it's value in data.table.

```
Expected Output:

    abc xyz   q1
 1:   1   1 0.25
 2:   2   1 0.44
 3:   3   1 0.58
 4:   4   1 0.68
 5:   5   1 0.76
 6:   1   2 0.50
 7:   2   2 0.88
 8:   3   2 1.16
 9:   4   2 1.37
10:   5   2 1.53
```

The ways I tried:

1st way:

```
df[, q1 := ifelse(abc == 1, (0.25 * xyz), ((0.25 * xyz) + 0.75 * shift(q1)) )]
```

It didn't work as q1 doesn't already exist

Comment: Is `xyz` always in increasing order so the `1` come first?

Comment: Your problem description is confusing. Apparently, you want the recursive formula: `q_1 = 0.25 * xyz, q_i = 0.25 * xyz + 0.75 * q_{i-1}`. Either, you need to create an explicit formula from this or you could quickly implement it as a loop with Rcpp.

Comment: @sindri_baldur No, xyz can have any value.

Comment: @Ronald , I want to know if there is a way in data.table by which one can refer to the previous row value of a newly created column. The most important part here is the shift(q1) .

Comment: I reiterate, you want to do a recursive calculation. That's not possible with data.table.

Comment: Just curious, why is recursive calculation is not possible in data.table? When it is a a very useful thing to have.

Comment: Because you can't implement it efficiently for the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive formulas can't be implemented with pure data.table. You could quickly implement it in Rcpp:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(abc = rep(1:5,2), xyz = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)))#
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
            NumericVector foo(const NumericVector xyz) {
            double n = xyz.length();
            NumericVector res(n);
            res[0] = 0.25 * xyz[0];
            for (double i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            res[i] = 0.25 * xyz[i] + 0.75 * res[i-1];
            }
            return res;
            }
            ")

df[, q1 := foo(xyz), by = rleid(cumprod(c(0, diff(abc))))]
    abc xyz        q1
# 1:   1   1 0.2500000
# 2:   2   1 0.4375000
# 3:   3   1 0.5781250
# 4:   4   1 0.6835938
# 5:   5   1 0.7626953
# 6:   1   2 0.5000000
# 7:   2   2 0.8750000
# 8:   3   2 1.1562500
# 9:   4   2 1.3671875
#10:   5   2 1.5253906
```

Alternatively, you'll have to derive an explicit formula.

Comment: Thanks @Ronald , what does 'by = rleid(cumprod(c(0, diff(abc))))' do?

Comment: Run `df[, rleid(cumprod(c(0, diff(abc))))]` to see what it does. (And my name is not Ronald.)